# What is the meaning of "quite" in the sentence "You are quite from me."

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "quite" in the following sentence?

> "You are **quite** from me."

My college classmate sent me a message after a while that I didn't see and talked to him. In this message he asked me "how are you?" then I told him that I'm Ok and asked him politely the same. He answered me that he's Ok as well and then wrote me "You are **quite** from me."

Iv'e checked in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quite) and I didn't understand which of the interpretations to choose. Also, based on this dictionary it is an *adverb* rather than *adjective* then I cannot understand how such sentence can be.

Comment: The real question is what does he mean by "from me"?  Distant literally? Distant figuratively?  **quite** means "to a significant degree".

Comment: Then shouldn't he say "You're quite *far* from me"? It's weird to me since he's a native English speaker. I asked him what does it mean and then he told me: "We haven’t talk for a while."

Comment: I was just taking a guess at what he might have been trying to say. It is not clear what he meant since "quite from me" isn't idiomatic. *quite far from me* would be idiomatic.  Perhaps he dropped a word accidentally when typing.   **quiet from me** is not idiomatic either.

Answer (score 1):

I think he meant to say **quiet to me**? It's **VERY** common for English speakers to misspell **quiet** as **quite**. That makes sense based on your comments. I think he was basically trying to say

> *you've been quiet*

as in I haven't heard from you in a while. I see this word frequently misspelled in Facebook posts, memes, texts, threads, forums, Twitter, etc. Sometimes it's due to auto correct, and others it's simple misspelling. I could be wrong in my assumption, but I'm basing that off your comments.

Comment: Maybe it's indeed a mistake to say "quiet" as you suggested, but if so, is it possible to say "You are quiet **from** me."?

Comment: That's the part that confused me as well. Either way he's made some mistake because "you're quite from me" is something I've never heard before. Sorry I bumped the wrong key on the app and posted an answer by accident:P